# Sending data to database exceeds maximum execution time of 30 seconds

Tags: php, ajax, json

I send data from JS with AJAX to PHP like that:

`$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: 'protected_page.php',
   data: JSON.stringify(distances),
   contentType: "application/json"
 });`

The data "distances" is structured - {id1:Array(95),id2:Array(95)...}. It has 95 IDs and for every id there are 95 integer values witch represent distances (basically a 95x95 matrix).

The data needs to be inserted into my table `u_id | i_id1 | i_id2 | distance`. Below is the PHP method that does that, but it exceeds the maximum execution time of 30 seconds and only ~700 rows out of ~10 000 reach the database. Should I change the structure of my database or can I make it more optimal somehow?

```
function postDistances2($mysqli){
 if ( getenv("REQUEST_METHOD") !== "POST" ) return;

 if ( $distance = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true) ) {
    $keys = [];
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    foreach ($distance as $key => $value) {
        array_push($keys,$key);
    }
    foreach($distance as $key=>$value){
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($value);$i++){
            if ($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO image_distances (u_id, i1_id, i2_id, distance) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)")) {
            $insert_stmt->bind_param('iiid', $user_id, $key, $keys[$i], $value[$i]);
            // Execute the prepared query.
            $insert_stmt->execute(); 
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only call `prepare` once. That's the point of it, really. Only bind parameters and execute from within the loop. I suspect that'll speed things up a bit, but probably not enough.

I think the best way to handle this is to send the JSON in batches. Bear in mind your server might hit heavy load at some point, so the batches should be fairly small. A progress indicator on the page might be appropriate here.

Another option could be to build a single SQL query, e.g. (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?). This will minimise the time your script is spending communicating with the database server.

Yet another option is to disable the maximum execution time. I certainly don't recommend this at all, but it's an option nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you, I solved the issue by building a multiple value insert statement and sent all the data in under 10 seconds, still not a fast time but it does the job :)

Comment: Would it be more efficient to send 20 insert statements 500 values each or 1 insert statement with 10 000 values?

Comment: I'd think the single query would be better, but you'd better check the settings on your server. In particular, `max_allowed_packet`. You can see this by running `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';`